# Query returning multiple identical rows instead one

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the tables: `juices`, `juice_ingredients` and `ingredients`.

The `juices` table has the attributes:

- name
- barcode

The `juice_ingredients` table has the attributes:

- juice_id
- ingredient_id

And the `ingredients` table has

- name
- optional (boolean)

For the sake of  customer's logistics various juices may have the same barcode, but with different ingredients, some of which are optional
I need select, by barcode, the single juice that has no contains optional ingredient among its ingredients.

I signed up four ingredients: water (optional: false), sugar (optional: true), pineapple pulp (optional: false) and mint (optional: true). And signed up four juices: one only with water and pineapple pulp, other with water, pineapple pulp and sugar, other with water, pineapple pulp and mint, and other with water, pineapple pulp, mint and sugar. All with the same barcode. I make a query to select only the juice make with non optional ingredients, in this case water and pineapple pulp.

```
SELECT *
FROM juices
INNER JOIN juice_ingredients ON (juice_ingredients.juice_id = juices.id)
INNER JOIN ingredients ON (juice_ingredients.ingredient_id = ingredients.id)
WHERE juices.barcode = '000000000001' AND ingredients.optional = false
```

But it was returning multiple rows. What should change this query to bring only one, or the juice containing no optional ingredients in the composition?

Comment: did you tried  `DISTINCT` i.e like `SELECT DISTINCT .....`

Comment: To make it more clear and simple: you want to see the rows of `juices` that are not referenced by `juice_ingredients` (you actually only want to see the ones with a given barcode and you expect to be just one of this kind. But am I right with my simplification? If so, post the complete definitions of `juices` and `juice_ingredients`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't specify which database you are using, you may have to adjust the SQL for your specific database:

```
select *
  from juices j
 where j.barcode = '000000000001'
   and not exists (select *
                     from juice_ingredients ji
                    inner join ingredients i
                       on (i.ingredient_id = ji.ingredient_id
                      and i.optional = true)
                    where ji.juice_id = j.juice_id)
```

Comment: I adapted you to Postgres, and it worked.

```...on (i.id = ji.ingredient_id ...) where ji.juice_id = j.id)```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with a `having` clause:

```
SELECT juices.*
FROM juices
JOIN juice_ingredients ON juice_ingredients.juice_id = juices.id
JOIN ingredients ON juice_ingredients.ingredient_id = ingredients.id
WHERE juices.barcode = '000000000001'
GROUP BY 1, 2
HAVING MAX(ingredients.optional::text) = 'false'
```

Comment: Bohemin, this was the returned error: ```ERROR:  function min(boolean) does not exist
LINE 7: HAVING MIN(ingredients.optional) = true
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
********** Error **********

ERROR: function min(boolean) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 226```

Comment: @RafaelLaurindo OK fixed (it would have worked in other DBs - postgres is so strict!)

Comment: It doesn't raise an error, but returns no records. :(

Comment: @RafaelLaurindo oops. got the logic around the wrong way (see edited answer). If you want *all* juices that don't have optional ingrediaents, remove the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: It works. Congratulations. Thank you too. But, why ```GROUP BY 1, 2```?

Comment: @rafa you need `group by 1, 2`, which means "group by columns number 1 and 2" - an alternate syntax to repeating to column expressions, because there's a `having` clause, plus it removes duplicates automatically